# Hours difference between time in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, case

I am trying to get the hours between the two dates using `DATEDIFF(HOUR, FromTime, ToTime)` but when the time is 00:00:00. And the I got the negative and wrong hours.

[image]

Code Below:

> ```
> select FromTime, ToTime, datepart(HH, FromTime) as fromtimehours,
> datepart(HH, ToTime) as totimehours, 
> DATEDIFF(HOUR, FromTime, ToTime) as totalhours
> from table
> ```

Comment: What about abs(datediff(HOUR, FromTime, ToTime))?  And how is totalhours "wrong"?

Comment: what should the negative numbers be?

Comment: I know the abs. It should be 16hours - 24hours = 8hours.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a date element to your FromTime and ToTime:  it is only time.  So a ToTime of zero, is seen as midnight of the starting day, not midnight of the next day.   You say you are trying to get the hours between two dates, but where is the date information?

Comment: Do you not have a full timestamp?  You need a date for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a case statement to catch if it is a negative value and then calculate properly:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, FromTime, ToTime) < 0 
THEN 24 - DATEPART(hour, FromTime) + DATEPART(hour, ToTime)
ELSE DATEDIFF(HOUR, FromTime, ToTime) 
END AS TotalHours
```

Comment: Might work as well if you added the negative result of the datediff to the 24 hours as well.  For example 24 + (-16) would give you the 8 hours you are looking for.