# how to write a sql to calculate working hours minus rest time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of rest time in work shift

```
Begin        end
12:00        12:30
17:30        18:30
```

Now I want to write a SQL to calculate actual working hours given the start and end time. For example if start at 9:00 and end at 15:00, the actual hours is 6-rest time=5.5 hours and if start at 9:00 and end at 20:00 the actual hours is 10 hours. How to write a procedure to check it in SQL server? Thx.

Comment: Have you [read this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042287/hours-difference-between-time-in-sql-server)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way using `DATEDIFF`

```
 select *, CONVERT(time(7),DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(s,S,E),'00:00:00')) from QQ
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01213d/1

for your case  column name will be

```
select *, CONVERT(time(7),DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(s,Begin,end),'00:00:00')) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no schema details to work with here, which means the following SQL is generic and will have to be altered to fit your db.

```
SELECT 
  (datediff(minute, shiftStartTime, shiftEndTime) 
  - datediff(minute,breakStartTime,breakEndTime)) / 60.0
FROM yourTable
```

Notes:

- If they can have multiple breaks, you need to sum up all the break times in minutes before deducting it from the shift period.
- the calculation is specifically in minutes because the datediff counts the number of boundaries passed, so the date diff in hours between 11:59 and 12:01 is 1, even though the break is 2 minutes, you would count that as 1 hour if you count hours using the function.

If you can provide more schema details, we would be able to craft a more complete statement.

Comment: Thanks, In my table schema, the shift start and end time is in two columns, one is  in date format '2018-08-16 00:00:00.000' and the other is like '09:00'.and the break start and end time is like '12:00' and '12:30' which has no date infomation.